# Is there any plugin to implement ACLs for Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acl, access-control

I would like find an Access Control Lists for Rails like this one:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html

In that ACL you have groups that will contain the users.
For each group you define which controllers and methods the user can execute.

I have not been able to find something robust and easy as the plugin developed for CakePHP.

What are the best current options for Rails 4?

Thank you.

Comment: I think what you might be looking at is pundit or cancancan(gems). I would personally go with pundit, because I hate the cancancan DSL and I feel Pundit allows me to be more expressive.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into [acl9](https://github.com/be9/acl9)? I have not used it, but it sounds like what you need.

If you don't need full-blown ACLs, and just a simple role system will suffice, check out [rollify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify).

Here are some good references for other options:

- http://awesome-ruby.com/#awesome-ruby-authorization
- https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization

Comment: I'm sorry for taking so long to answer. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the gems that people give as examples for ACLs are actually focused on role-based access control rather than access control lists.

You probably want to set up something like [NFSv4 Access Control Lists](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs4_acl) which allow you to control which users get to read, write, delete, etc., which objects.

Basically there aren't any gems for this. My guess is that the reason is that ACLs are really very easy to implement with a single database table, but the exact details are pretty much database-specific as far as which models are covered by ACLs.

Comment: @maurymmarques If you found my answer useful can you upvote it?